# javascript calculator answer modification

Tags: javascript

I'm currently on the 8th video of the "Udemy - Javascript for Beginners" course

And I'm just starting to learn how to express myself in javascript so regarding his tutorial where I wrote some basic code for a calculator I got curious of how I can make some modifications.

When pressing the button you get the numerical result replacing the sentance, fine. But right after the sum of the calculation I'd like to add something along the lines of: not bad!

and while I'm at it, why not have the button text change to something like: fine...

So, how to do this?

Javascript:

```
var number1 = 234;
var number2 = 454;

function addNumbers(){

    var calculation = number1 + number2;
    document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = calculation;
}
```

HTML:

```
<p id="p">How much do you like Javascript on a scale between 1-1000?</p>
    <button onclick="addNumbers();" id="p_button" class=" btn btn-primary">
    let's see</button>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't use rude/abusive language on SO. This site is for **professional** developers. Be polite, nice here. :)

Comment: sorry, will take note of that :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `+` operator to [concatenate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#String_operators) strings and variables, i.e. put them together:

```js
var a = "hello ";
document.write(a+" world!");
```

So, you would want to use:

```
document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = calculation+", not bad!";
```

And, for your request to change the button text:

```
document.getElementById("p_button").innerHTML = "New text";
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy you just need to add string with  calculation variable. as following in your addNumbers() function.

```
function addNumbers(){
    var calculation = number1 + number2;
    document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = calculation + "not bad!";
}
```